# Azure Activity Log List API not returning Health Event

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-diagnostics

Azure Activity Logs API 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/activitylogs/activitylogs_list

does not return Activity Logs related to

Health Event InProgress
Health Event Resolved

in the results list. However I am able to see it in portal https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ActivityLog/ActivityLogBlade
why is that?

---Edit-------------------
Adding Screenshot of the HealthEvent from the Azure portal.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the results list in the portal as screenshot?

Comment: Added the screenshot of the health event, these dont show up in the API result

Answer (score 1):

If you set `api-version=2017-03-01-preview` this will return the health events.  I will followup with the team that owns this API to see why it isn't documented yet.

For reference, to find things like this in the future, you can use a web debugger (ie. Fiddler, or the F12 network debugger in your browser) to see the HTTP request being made by the Azure portal.  You will see a request to https://management.azure.com/batch?api-version=2015-11-01, and the body of that will include the REST API call being made on your behalf (https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2017-03-01-preview&filter=...)

Comment: Thank you this works. Thanks for the tip with Browser Debugger. I am assuming that every thing that happens in my Subscription will have an event log generated. Since it says preview, does that mean its not production ready?

Comment: -preview can mean different things.  If it isn't documented yet then I wouldn't take any production dependencies on it.

Comment: The "if it isn't documented don't take a production dependency" also applies to some of the API calls that you can find when watching the portal HTTP traffic.  You may see API calls to URLs or APIs that aren't documented.  You should consider these internal implementation details and not take any dependencies on them as they could change at any time.

Comment: Thanks, Could you please followup with the team and confirm if this API can be trusted for use? That would be of great help